# How do I revert local files to how it was before git pull

Tags: git

I was trying to pull a remote repo to my local file and forgot to stash my local files before the action. How can I revert this process because my local changes are gone and I've made a lot of changes?

Comment: If you really had unsaved but modified local files which you did not commit, stage, or stash, then unfortunately your work may be lost.  If you are using an editor which maintains a local history then you should _immediately_ check the local history of the files in question.

Comment: Git will not let you pull if you have local changes that would be affected. So there is no problem.  If the pull succeeded, everything is still there.

Comment: Oh, _unsaved_ local changes? I didn’t think of that. An unsaved change is not a change. :(

Comment: Do your files appear in `git status` ? If you have the autostash option on, git may have stashed your changes on its own : check `git stash list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really an answer.  Unfortunately, there *isn't* an answer.  In general, Git should not have lost your files, unless you explicitly told it to.  There are a number of ways to tell Git *lose my files for me* though.  Without seeing the exact set of commands you ran, nobody can give you anything other than general advice.

---

In general, a pull or merge that *would* lose unsaved work should fail:

```
$ git merge
Updating 51ebf55b93..98cedd0233
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    Makefile
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
```

with `git pull` producing the same message on my machine running Git 2.24.0.

Some earlier Git versions will give a different error, and some truly ancient Git versions really did sometimes wreck your work-tree if you had uncommitted work.  You don't mention which version of Git you have, but if it's at least Git 2.0 this should not be a problem.

Nonetheless, I recommend *avoiding* `git pull`.  What `git pull` does is run two Git commands.  The first one is simply `git fetch`.  For instance, running `git pull origin` runs `git fetch origin`; running `git pull origin master` runs `git fetch origin master`; and running `git pull` with no options runs `git fetch` with no options.

It's the *second* command that's dangerous—or, well, *dangerous* is too strong a word: the *second* command can mess with your own work.  It's always safe to run `git fetch`.<sup>1</sup>  Learn how to read what `git fetch` prints—it's kind of confusing, but it all means things.  See below for details.

The second command that `git fetch` runs defaults to `git merge`.  Learn what `git merge` does, and how it affects your current work-tree.  Learn its options: `--ff-only`, `--no-ff`, and so on.

You can choose to have `git pull` run `git rebase` as its second command.  Learn what `git rebase` does, and how it affects not only your current work-tree, but also the commits that you rebase in the process.  Learn its options, such as `-i` for interactive rebase.  Learn that `git rebase` is in effect like a series of repeated `git cherry-pick` commands,<sup>2</sup> that uses Git's *detached HEAD* mode.<sup>3</sup>

Then, after running `git fetch` and seeing what `git fetch` did, decide whether you want to look at the commits that came in, and whether you want a merge—with or without `--ff-only` or `--no-ff`—or whether you want a rebase.  You now have the space and time to run `git log` if you want, and space and time to decide on rebase vs merge.

Once you're *very* familiar with all these elements, *and* are pretty sure what's happened in whatever repository you will `git fetch` from, *then* it becomes safe to pick merge vs rebase in advance and use the convenience `git pull` short-cut to run `git fetch` and then immediately run the second command too.

---

<sup>1</sup>If you fiddle with internal `git fetch` settings, you *can* make this unsafe.  Think of it as rewiring your light switches so that the wall near the switch has an electrified plate.  If you don't go breaking your setup, `git fetch` will be safe.  If you do, that's on you.

<sup>2</sup>One kind of rebase really does use `git cherry-pick`.  Another uses `git format-patch` and `git apply` instead.  This second kind of rebase is in most ways not as good, but does go faster, so it used to be the default—but Git 2.26 is about to switch the default to use the cherry-pick method.

<sup>3</sup>A rebase can stop in the middle and need help from you to fix it.  When that happens, Git continues to be in this detached HEAD mode.  Hence, you should learn what detached HEAD mode is about.

---

#### What `git fetch` does

Remember that Git is really all about *commits*.  Each commit holds a full and complete snapshot of all of your files.  And, each commit has some *metadata:* some information *about* the commit, that's not part of the committed data but that Git wants or needs to retain for you as well.  Each commit gets a unique hash ID: a big ugly string of letters and digits,<sup>4</sup> rather than a nice simple number just counting up (1, 2, 3, ...).

The real magic of a commit hash ID—and the reason it has to be so big and ugly—is that it's unique across *every* Git repository everywhere.  Remember that not only do you have *your* Git repository, or maybe multiple ones, everyone else has *their* repositories too.  There's another Git over at `origin`.  That's the repository you cloned, when you ran:

```
git clone <url>
```

Your Git made a new, empty repository, stuck the URL you gave into it under the name `origin`, and then called up the other Git over at that URL.  That other Git then offered, to your Git, its commits, telling your Git about *its* branch names (and tag names, and other names, but we'll concentrate on branch names here).  Your Git had their Git give you *all* of their commits, and your Git put *all* of those commits into *your* database-of-all-commits.  Then your Git took their *branch* names and copied them to make your *remote-tracking* names.

Their `master` became your `origin/master`.  Their `develop`, if they had one, became your `origin/develop`.  The pattern here is straightforward: for each branch they have, your Git creates an `origin/`-prefixed variant.  In *this* name, your Git stashes the hash ID that *their* Git says goes with *their* branch names.

In short, your remote-tracking names remember what *their* branch names were.

But you cloned that Git repository *seconds* ago.  Or maybe even minutes, or hours, or (horror) days or weeks.  Much has happened since then!  (An active repository can gain dozens of commits every few seconds, in some cases.)

So, to pick up *new* stuff from them, you run:

```
git fetch origin
```

(or just `git fetch`, which generally defaults to using `origin` anyway).  Your Git calls up their Git, like it did earlier.  It has them list out their branch names (and tag and other names) like before.  Their `master` may be different now!  If so, they may have commits that your Git doesn't.  Your Git now gets, from their Git, the *new* commits they have, that you don't.<sup>5</sup>  Your Git adds these to *your* collection, and now you have them—and now your Git updates your *remote-tracking names*.

I have a clone (well, one of several) of the official Linux kernel, which I tend to update very sporadically, on a handy test machine here.  Let's run `git fetch` on that one now and observe:

```
$ git fetch
remote: Enumerating objects: 243814, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (243814/243814), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (45189/45189), done.
remote: Total 243814 (delta 198891), reused 242574 (delta 198039)
Receiving objects: 100% (243814/243814), 76.86 MiB | 4.94 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (198891/198891), completed with 12626 local objects.
From git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux
   0f1a7b3fac05..5ad0ec0b8652  master     -> origin/master
 * [new tag]                   [snip lots of new tags]
```

We see a bunch of messages here.  The first few start with `remote:`.  These are actually messages generated by *their* Git, that our Git just copies through so we can see them.  They talk about enumerating, counting, and compressing *objects*.  These objects are the internal representation that Git uses for each of its database objects: commits, trees, blobs, and annotated tags.  Every commit uses some number of trees and blobs to hold its files, in a frozen-for-all-time snapshot.  Commits can *share* trees and blobs to save space: if a commit re-uses a file, or a whole tree full of files, from an earlier or later commit, they just share their trees and/or blobs.

The *counting* step counts how many of these objects they have, that I don't, that they are going to send.  In general, they won't send ones that I *do* have.<sup>6</sup>  So this counting happened for many commits and their files, and some annotated tags (the `new tag` stuff above), and it counted out nearly a quarter-million objects.

Then, they compressed some of those objects—in this case, about 20% of the objects (which will generally account for much more percentage of the total bulk of the network transfer), and sent them to my Git.  We now get out of the `remote:`-prefixed lines, to where my Git reconstructed the original objects and added them to my repository.

Last, my Git updated my remote-tracking name, `origin/master`, based on their `master`.  **This is the really important line:**

```
   0f1a7b3fac05..5ad0ec0b8652  master     -> origin/master
```

The two hash IDs here are:

- `0f1a7b3fac05`: my `origin/master` held this hash ID *before* my `git fetch` updated it;
- `5ad0ec0b8652`: my `origin/master` held this hash ID *after* my `git fetch` updated it.

After this, we see *their* branch name, `master`, then this ASCII arrow `->`, then my remote-tracking name, `origin/master`.

This tells me that my `origin/master` has been adjusted to add new commits, without discarding any existing commits.  If I want to know *how many* commits I just got, I can now count them:

```
$ git rev-list --count 0f1a7b3fac05..5ad0ec0b8652
31244
```

So, since the last time I ran `git fetch`, I've just picked up another 31,244 commits, all on their `master` / my `origin/master`.

(I also picked up a bunch of new tags, for kernel versions 5.4 and 5.5 and the upcoming 5.6.)

The short version of all this is that you can pick up the `git fetch` output here and cut-and-paste the two hash IDs into a `git log` or `git rev-list --count` to look at the commits, or see how many there were.

This particular repository doesn't have branches that get `git push --force` applied to them.  The Git repository for Git itself, however, does.  My copy of that one here is much more up to date so I can't show actual `git fetch` output, but it would look like this:

```
 + old...new  pu     -> origin/pu (forced update)
```

This output has three things that are different, besides the two hash IDs being different (and fake in this case):

1. it has a `+` at the front, indicating that the update was forced;
2. it has three dots between the two hash IDs, indicating that the update was forced; and
3. it ends with `(forced update)`, indicating that the update was forced.

There is no difference between these three indicators.  It's just ***very important*** that my Git let me know that this was a *forced* update, i.e., I now have some commit(s) in *my* repository, left over, that *they* decided should be thrown out.  If I'm *using* their `pu` branch—my `origin/pu` branch—in some way, I should be aware of this.

The `pu` (Proposed Update or PickUp) branch in Git is one that all Git developers, and other hangers-on, have agreed is regularly rebased, or rewound and rebuilt.  Commits in *this* branch may be replaced with new and improved ones, or discarded entirely; we all agree that we will deal with this, not complaining about it.

---

<sup>4</sup>Technically, the hash ID is just a bit or byte string.  Git currently uses SHA-1 hashes, which are 160 bits long, and then represents these hash values as 40-character hexadecimal numbers.  Git is gradually moving towards replacing these with SHA-2 hashes, which are 256 bits long.

<sup>5</sup>Note that you may have added *your own* commits to your repository before this point.  That's why Git can't use simple sequential numbers.  Suppose you got 1000 commits from them, numbered 1 through 1000.  Then you make two commits of your own, numbers 1001 and 1002.  Now you call up their Git and they have three new commits, numbered 1001 through 1003.  What do we do about these overlapping numbers?

It is actually possible to keep some local numbers.  Mercurial, which is as capable as Git, does so.  The local numbers are sometimes handy—but they're not as usable as one might like, in the end.  Git just doesn't bother with them.

<sup>6</sup>This generality makes a lot of assumptions.  Git trades off being totally precise vs doing this with minimal information and doing it quickly.  If your Git and their Git had a longer conversation, which would take more network bandwidth, their Git could sometimes omit some objects, which would take less network bandwidth.

---

#### Why you need a second Git command

When `git fetch` obtains new commits, they just sit there in your repository database.  You can't *see* any of these directly.  You can run `git log` on them, or `git show`.  You can use the commit hash IDs that you find with your remote-tracking names.  But in general, you'll have to *do something* with those commits to get the files.

If you make your *own* commits, the *something* that you need to do now is usually some form of *incorporate their work into my work*.  The two main Git commands to do this are `git merge`, which *merges* their work into yours, and `git rebase`, which *copies* your original commits to new-and-improved commits, with the improvement—at least, you hope it's an improvement—being to put those commits *after* **their** new commits, instead of alongside theirs.

Both of these commands affect *your* branches.

Fetch does not: `git fetch` gets you new *commits* but your existing commits are totally unaffected by adding *new* ones.  The new ones have different big ugly hash IDs.  Every new commit has a different hash ID than every other commit.  Commits don't have small numbers; nobody will make commit #3, as commit #3 doesn't ever exist.  All `git fetch` does is add new commits and update your remote-tracking names.

But both `git merge` and `git rebase` need to use your *work-tree*.  Your work-tree or working tree (Git mostly uses the longer term now) is where Git *extracts* the commit snapshots, so that you can see them and work on / with them—hence the name *work-tree:* it's where you do your work.  The merge operation often needs to change your work-tree around.  The rebase operation runs repeated `git cherry-picks`, each of which often needs to change your work-tree around.  Both `git merge` and `git cherry-pick` can have *merge conflicts*, which you have to resolve: these mean Git couldn't figure it out on its own.  In this case, Git leaves you a mess in your work-tree, that you must fix.

In both cases, the final result of a merge or rebase can change which commit is the *last* commit in *your* branch.  They always work with your *current* branch.  So these two commands need a lot of careful use, and it's always wise to run `git status` first, to make sure your current branch is (a) the right branch and (b) ready for a merge or rebase operation.

Feel free to use `git pull`, just know that it will (1) run `git fetch`, then (2) run one of these other commands.  You won't get a chance to look at, and make decisions based on, the `git fetch` output: you've committed in advance to an immediate `git merge` or `git rebase`.<sup>7</sup>  There is nothing fundamentally wrong with this, but I prefer to keep these two operations separate.

(I have an alias, `git mff`, that runs `git merge --ff-only`, which is what I often use after `git fetch`.  That, combined with a brief glance at the fetch output and the current status, is usually what *I* want, and if it doesn't work, *then* I want to look more closely at everything.)

---

<sup>7</sup>There are some unusual circumstances where the second part of `git pull` is neither merge *nor* rebase.  For instance, `git pull` into a totally empty repository requires doing a `git checkout` instead, so it does that.  In ancient Git (1.5.something or 1.6.something), this lost me a day or two of work, once, because it was not coded carefully and I hadn't committed yet.  That's one of the reasons I avoid `git pull`: it's burned me more than once, with that particular case being the worst one.